# Android TabLayout Layout to show Sequence of execution

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have to show sequence execution in app, all my screens are already ready and usable in app inherited from Activity, lets say ActivityA , ActivityB , ActivityC.
App bottom layout will only show sequence execution, they are not swipeable/clickable after 1st step completion 1st tab will be highlighted , after 2nd step completion, 1st & 2nd tab both will be highlighted.
**Whats the correct way to achieve desired requirement.Should i use TabLayout? can i reuse my existing activity in TabLayout? can i show multiple tabs selection using tablayout?** 
One thing more 1st step has ActivityA , it already has TabLayouts and fragments inside.

[image]

Comment: You can use tab layout or bottom navigation view. After previous step executed will it able to select again if user wants to edit it?

Comment: @Piyush No after 1st step execution , user cant edit it even cant go back and only 2nd step will be shown to user, while user cant click/swipe any sequence tabs. he has to follow sequence defined by system.

Comment: Then you can use bottom navigation view because it is not swipable as @RobinHood answered.

Comment: is it done or not erum?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, I will suggest you that you can use Constraint layout at the bottom and use textview or buttons instead of the bottom navigation and can handle manually these things as per your requirements

Comment: i am little bit confused , will i be able to show activity everytime within the container or need to use Fragments. As my all screens are ready and inherited with activity

Comment: yeah must have to use Fragments it's best practice in some projects I have also use this same way and its works

Comment: can i load my current activity inside fragment , instead of converting my existing activities into fragment ? as my app is complete and these activities are being used in app as well , now we need another feature with this dynamic sequence, so is this good approach to shift all activities into fragments due to this sequence change ?

Comment: yes its good approach to convert activity to fragment and you can manage the sequences very efficiently I will suggest you To convert activity to fragment

Comment: While one of activity already has fragment and tablayout , so will i shift into fragments and childfragments? Please do confirm as this is going to disturb whole app

Comment: You can set the parent as a fragment and that have tab layout and in under tab layout you can use fragments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200585/discussion-between-erum-and-ashok-songara).

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) can work, simply you need to enable/disable next buttons as per completion of current (First) button process.

Initially set all button disable except the first one by looping.

```
 private void enableBottomBar(){
    for (int i = 0; i < mBottomMenu.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        if(i==0){
            mBottomMenu.getMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(true);    
        }else{
            mBottomMenu.getMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Later you can enable the next buttons by passing position.

```
private void enableBottomBar(boolean enable, int position){
    mBottomMenu.getMenu().getItem(position).setEnabled(enable);

}
```

Comment: @Piyush https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow